# How to edit the second line in text file using batch?

Tags: batch-file, edit

Do you have any idea how to edit a text file's second line in batch?
I need this for my login system for batch. I need to edit the second line in a file called Data.db

Comment: Please show your effort then ask about the problem you are facing?

Comment: There are numerous ways to edit a text file.  Give more information about the editing, because the method used can depend on the task.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't say what your system is I presume it could be a Windows or a Unix-Linux favor. I think the simple "ed" does the trick. It is included in any Unix-Linux and has been ported to Windows by the [GnuWin project](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). Direct link for ed is [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ed.htm).